# Jupyter notebook tensorflow pandas plotting error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, matplotlib

i tried to concat 2 data frame, first one is X as number from 1 to 112

```
x_data = np.arange(1,113,1)
x_df = pd.DataFrame(data=x_data,columns = ['X'])
```

the second one is gold price from 2 may until 2 october from :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tFDgfIJof03vA0VGiqgRsDBZsOdmec2g/view?usp=sharing

after i concat it using

```
my_data = pd.concat([x_df,emas_df],axis=1)
```

the data look like this
[image: concat of x_df and emas_df]

i would like to plot 50 sample from my_data and scatter it with "X" as x, and "Terakhir" (meaning last price in my language) as y using

```
my_data.sample(n=50).plot(kind='scatter',x='X',y='Terakhir')
```

i get an error of

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-ca1cd423cab6> in <module>
----> 1 my_data.sample(n=50).plot(kind='scatter',x='X',y='Terakhir')

c:\users\tila\anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2625                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   2626                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2627                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   2628     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   2629 

c:\users\tila\anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   1867                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1868                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 1869                  **kwds)
   1870 
   1871 

c:\users\tila\anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1650         if isinstance(data, DataFrame):
   1651             plot_obj = klass(data, x=x, y=y, subplots=subplots, ax=ax,
-> 1652                              kind=kind, **kwds)
   1653         else:
   1654             raise ValueError("plot kind %r can only be used for data frames"

c:\users\tila\anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __init__(self, data, x, y, s, c, **kwargs)
    808             # the handling of this argument later
    809             s = 20
--> 810         super(ScatterPlot, self).__init__(data, x, y, s=s, **kwargs)
    811         if is_integer(c) and not self.data.columns.holds_integer():
    812             c = self.data.columns[c]

c:\users\tila\anaconda3\envs\tfdeeplearning\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __init__(self, data, x, y, **kwargs)
    785             raise ValueError(self._kind + ' requires x column to be numeric')
    786         if len(self.data[y]._get_numeric_data()) == 0:
--> 787             raise ValueError(self._kind + ' requires y column to be numeric')
    788 
    789         self.x = x

ValueError: scatter requires y column to be numeric
```

what do i need to do in order to be able to scatter X and Y with respective columns?

Comment: As the Error says - just check the "y='Terakhir' " where 'Terakhir'  should be of the numeric datatype.

Comment: it seems like it was not counted as numeric, but all the data is filled with numbers.. so i dont really know what caused the data to not be considered numeric nor how to convert those non numeric into int/float

Comment: In that case share the few records of all columns, also show the output of  my_data.info()

Comment: allright, the picture have been edited and its now on the thread sir

Comment: Posted a detailed answer for you. TC @Tartila Sahid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **"Terakhir" Series** is of **string data type** and having a **comma in each of it**.

[image]

Do the following to **remove comma** and **convert it into numeric data type**:

[image]

**Finally, Plot it!**

[image]

Comment: not even just answerin it, but you even give detailed and comprehensive reason as to why the error happened! i am very grateful for your help

Comment: sir, if by any chance would you help me again? i have difficulty on regression based on this data at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195865/regression-with-tensorflow-using-gold-price-database. thank you for your time