# Regression with Tensorflow using gold price database

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a regression to predict gold price from the datasets of 2 may-2 october.

First of all I made an X as a listed number of 112 days:

```
x_data = np.arange(1,113,1)
x_df = pd.DataFrame(data=x_data,columns = ['X'])
```

Then I use the dataset of gold from
he second one is gold price from 2 may until 2 october from : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tFDgfIJof03vA0VGiqgRsDBZsOdmec2g/view?usp=sharing
Price is in USD at "Terakhir".

After converting the price of terakhir into USD, I concat it using

```
emas_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tila\Documents\BOT\dataemas.csv")
for index in range(0,len(emas_df["Terakhir"])):
    emas_df["Terakhir"][index] = emas_df["Terakhir"][index].replace(",","")
    
my_data = pd.concat([x_df,emas_df],axis=1)
my_data["Terakhir"] = pd.to_numeric(my_data["Terakhir"])
terakhir = my_data["Terakhir"]
y_true = (terakhir.values).T
```

And I plot scatter between X and the gold price "Terakhir" using

```
my_data.sample(n=50).plot(kind='scatter',x='X',y='Terakhir')
```

This is where the regression code starts, I use the code:

```
batch_size = 2
m = tf.Variable(0.45453853)
b = tf.Variable(0.4537617)
xph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch_size])
yph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batch_size])
y_model = m*xph + b
error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(yph-y_model))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
train = optimizer.minimize(error)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    
    batches = 50
    for i in range(batches):
        
        rand_ind = np.random.randint(len(x_data),size=batch_size)
        
        feed = {xph:x_data[rand_ind], yph:y_true[rand_ind]}
        
        sess.run(train,feed_dict = feed)
        
    model_m,model_b = sess.run([m,b])
```

With that I then plot the regression along with the actual scattered data with

```
y_hat = x_data*model_m + model_b

my_data.sample(n=50).plot(kind='scatter',x='X',y='Terakhir')
plt.plot(x_data,y_hat,'r')
```

But I always gets incorrect regression prediction as can be seen on the graph

[image: failed prediction]

Any idea on how to make my regression precise?

Comment: Please do **not** post Python code as Javascript snippets (edited)!

Comment: Is using tensorflow a must? Because if all you want to do is linear regression, [scipy.stats.linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) might be a better solution.